# Target class [FeedController] does not exist: Laravel 9 - I encounter an issue using patch in editing through modal

Tags: php, laravel-9

Here is my route: I tried using Route::patch('/update/{id}', [FeedController::class, 'update']); but I encounter the same error.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\FeedController;
Route::get('/feed', [FeedController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/feed', [FeedController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/feed', [FeedController::class, 'index']);
Route::delete('/feed/delete/{id}', 'FeedController@delete')->name('feed.delete');
Route::patch('/update/{id}', ['as' => 'feed.update', 'uses' => 'FeedController@update']);
```

Here is my Controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $feed = Feed::find($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $feed->fill($input)->save();

    return redirect('feed')->with('success', 'Changes Saved Successfully!'); 
}
```

Here is my Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$item->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalForEdit" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <div style="center-align">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalForEdit" >Edit Post</h5>
    </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('feed.update',['id' => $item->id]) }}" id="editForm">
        {!! Form::model($feeds, [ 'method' => 'patch','route' => ['feed.update', $item->id] ]) !!}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="control-group col-12">
                        <label for="title">{{$item->id}}</label>
                        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('title', $item->title, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group col-12 mt-2">
                        <label for="content">Content</label>
                        {!! Form::label('content', 'content') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('content', $item->content, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="feed"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button type="submit" value="POST" class="btn btn-success">Update and save changes</button></a>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my View:

```
<!-- Loop for Post-->
@foreach($feeds as $item)
<div class="row" id="datatable">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body px-0 pb-3 pt-1">
          <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
            <img src="../assets/img/romeo.jpg" class="avatar avatar-circle me-3" style="border-radius: 50%" alt="user1">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">User 1</h6>
                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">user1@gmail.com</p>
                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{ $item->updated_at->format('m/d/Y h:i A') }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        <div class="card-header pb-0" style="text-align: center; ">
          <h5>{{ $item->title }}</h5>
          <div class="card-body" >
            <div >
            <p class="mb-0 text-sm">{{ $item->content }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#edit{{$item->id}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>
        <a href="#delete{{$item->id}}" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>
        @include('modal')
    </div>
</div>
 @endforeach
```

When I try to update the content of my feed this error appears "Target class [FeedController] does not exist." Can anyone help me with this problem I've been trying to solve it for hours?

When I also try to use the command "php artisan route:list" this error appears:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 
Target class [FeedController] does not exist.
at
```

C:\Users\Name\Desktop\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Conta iner\Container.php:879
875▕
876▕         try {
877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
880▕         }
881▕
882▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
883▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

1   [internal]:0
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

2   C:\Users\Milbert\Desktop\softUI-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
ReflectionException::("Class "FeedController" does not exist")

Comment: Can you show the full FeedController, or at least the namespace at the top? Also, where is FeedController.php located in your project?

Comment: You're also mixing old style routes (`'FeedController@update'`) with new style routes (`[FeedController::class, 'index']`). Switch them all to the new style.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Feed;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



Here is the top of my feedcontroller and the location of my controller is in app/http/contollers